# Sub-pages of Custom Taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am trying to create fixed sub-pages of a custom taxonomy, which is more vexing that it might sound. Here's a scenario to describe the problem:

Let's say you have a website about movies. You write lots of stories about movies, so you create a custom taxonomy called 'Movies' where you add Citizen Kane, Die Hard, and Avatar. Eventually, you have 50,000 movie pages, which look like this:

```
/movie/gremlins/
/movie/brewsters-millions/
```

Those pages contain all of your posts, but you also start adding metadata (ACF fields) to those pages — length, cast, trailers, photos, and so forth. So far so good.

But then, you eventually realize you have so much data on those pages that you want to create fixed subpages for some pieces of metadata, which might look like this:

```
/movie/gremlins/cast/
/movie/brewsters-millions/cast/
```

How would you architect this? Abstractly, this is the pathing we seek:

```
/[custom taxonomy]/[term]/[sub page]/
```

The front and back will always be the same, so one could say it actually looks like this in practice:

```
/movie/[term]/cast/
```

All of the data for the cast page is located in the parent's ACF fields. I think I just need `/movie/[term]/cast/` to resolve to a specific template... possibly even the same template that  `/movie/[term]/` resolves to. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Or likely there's some other completely different way to do this.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm assuming that your `instance` is actually your `term`. Why not just create a page called `cast`  and assign the term to the page (gremlins or whatever)? That would give you the URL you desire. You could then exclude the cast page from the results of your loop on the term archive if required.

Comment: Yes, instance is term. (Edited that to be more clear.) I think your solution involves creating 50,000 cast pages? Otherwise how do I pass in each term's metadata?

Comment: Oh I see - so your meta is where currently? Term meta?

Comment: Yes, all of the metadata is associated with the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it something like this.

First, register a new query var, so WP will acknowledge its existence:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'cast';
    return $query_vars;
});
```

Next, add a rewrite rule, which converts the pretty permalink version of your URL behind the scenes:

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^movie/([^/]+)/cast/?$',
        'index.php?movie=$matches[1]&cast=1',
        'top' );
} );
```

(You'll probably need to flush permalinks at this stage.)

Finally, add a clause into your archive (or whatever template you're using) to detect the query var, and act accordingly:

```
if ( get_query_var('cast') ) {
    // Do what you need to do,
    // probably grab the term and use that
    // to display the term meta
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Exactly what I needed, thank you.